# Printing another program in c

Tags: c

In the original code I have a line:

```
input = scanf("%c%c%c%c%c", &input_key[0], &input_key[1], &input_key[2], &input_key[3], &input_key[4]);
```

since I have to print the program out I did:

```
printf("   input = scanf(\"%c%c%c%c%c\", &input_key[0], &input_key[1], &input_key[2], &input_key[3], &input_key[4]);\n");
```

however the output came out to:

```
input = scanf("dd≡Ç", &input_key[0], &input_key[1], &input_key[2], &input_key[3], &input_key[4]);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a special character in `printf` that is replaced by an input argument. If you want to print the `%` literal, you should escape it through `%%`.

So your code should be:

```
printf("   input = scanf(\"%%c%%c%%c%%c%%c\", &input_key[0], &input_key[1], &input_key[2], &input_key[3], &input_key[4]);\n");
```